# IDE where compile-on-save works in a multi modules maven project

Tags: eclipse, maven, netbeans, intellij-idea

When working with NetBeans and Maven all is fine except a minor hassle with multi maven projects. Imagine I have the 'tools' module dependent on the 'core' module. In order to use the recently changed 'core' from 'tools' I have to re-install the 'core'.

Or should I switch to a different IDE? But [IntelliJ](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16198604/194609) and [Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7783721/194609) seem to have problems as well (is this true?). How do you do it?

Of course, this should work for running, debugging and testing a project.

[**Update**] NetBeans 7.4 [has improved on this](http://forums.netbeans.org/topic54949.html) but as stated still some issues.

Comment: *But IntelliJ and Eclipse seem to have problems as well.* What do you mean by that? You mean that they have the same problems as you describe (which is wrong)? Or that they have other problems (which may certainly be true but what software does not have problems)?

Comment: From the posts I linked I probably got the wrong impressions. I don't mean in general having problems (just related to compile-on-save+multi module). E.g. for a colleague his IntelliJ and this CoS+mm did not work. Or do you have pointers for such a setup?

Comment: I have never understood why `compile-on-save` is so important. In IntelliJ 12 it has been introduced as well but normally in IntelliJ you just press Ctrl+F9 instead (build) which saves all unsaved files and builds all those. IntelliJ handles Multi-Module maven projects like a charm. Everything you change in one module is immediately reflected in the dependent modules. No need to do `mvn install`.

Comment: what are the issues you encounter with 7.4 dev builds?

Comment: @mkleint I did not test it yet but see the linked forum -> there the user reported some (I'll test later today)

Comment: ok, FYI the problems reported in the forum thread are only relevant to netbeans platform based application execution.

Comment: @mkleint thanks! Cannot wait to try this out. Would be really nice if that would work!

Comment: @mkleint This works! Nice!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how it works in IntelliJ with a maven multi module project.

Structure:

```
.
├── pom.xml
├── module-1
|   ├── pom.xml
|   └── src
|       └── main
|           └── java
|               └── com
|                   └── stackoverflow
|                       └── foo
|                           └── Foo.java
└── module-2
    ├── pom.xml
    └── src
        └── main
            └── java
                └── com
                    └── stackoverflow
                        └── bar
                            └── Bar.java
```

`Bar` extends `Foo` so `module-2` has a dependency on `module-1`.

`pom.xml`

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.stackoverflow</groupId>
<artifactId>multi-module-idea</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>

<name>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</name>

<properties>
    <mainClass/>
    <argument/>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<modules>
    <module>module-1</module>
    <module>module-2</module>
</modules>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.stackoverflow</groupId>
            <artifactId>module-1-idea</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.14</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

</project>
```

`module-1\pom.xml`

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.stackoverflow</groupId>
        <artifactId>multi-module-idea</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>module-1-idea</artifactId>

    <name>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</name>

</project>
```

`module-2\pom.xml`

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.stackoverflow</groupId>
        <artifactId>multi-module-idea</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>module-2-idea</artifactId>

    <name>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</name>

    <properties>
        <mainClass>maba.java.module2.App</mainClass>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.stackoverflow</groupId>
            <artifactId>module-1-idea</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

When this project is loaded into IntelliJ (by `File | Open...` and pointing to the `pom.xml` at the root) it will set up all module dependencies automatically. **NB** It is forbidden to use the `maven-idea-plugin` and `mvn idea:idea`. That module has not been updated since 2008.

[image]

Make sure that `Make project automatically` is checked (same as compile-on-save).

[image]

Now here is the code sample and everything looks nice (no compilation errors).

[image]

And now I change the `getText()` method to `getTextMessage()` in the `Foo` class and wait a couple of seconds (no need to save just wait for auto-save and then auto-compile) and the result is shown here.

[image]

---

**Conclusion**

IntelliJ can handle changes in other maven modules on the fly. Any changes in the dependent modules are immediately reflected even when using compile-on-save.

Comment: One quick question: Is the dependencyManagement + the dependency to the module-1 in the parent pom necessary?

Comment: @Karussell That's just a habit of mine. It simplifies maven releases. You don't have to specify the version of `module-1-idea` in the `module-2-idea` pom file. At least it used to be a problem with maven releases that it couldn't find all places to update version from `-SNAPSHOT` to stable releases in a multi module project. As said it is just a habit of mine. It should work by using versions directly in the module pom as well.

Comment: I'm not familiar with intelliJ, how do I create a run configuration for maven? The run button is grayed out .. but when hitting 'run' for one file this automatic build works accross multiple project :) !

Comment: You have to press the little dropdown menu to the left of the run button. It is a little arrow `v` that will show you all run configuration once they have been configured.